# Merge two sequential SQL query into a single SQL query for max and join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, merge, max

I have two SQL query which i execute sequentially.

1. ```
   select max(last_updated_date) as recent_date
       from TRANSACTION where quality='P' and TYPE='Car'
   ```
2. ```
   select * from CAR 
   JOIN
   (
   select TRAN_ID,LAST_UPDATED_DATE from TRANSACTION 
   ) on TRANSACTION.TRAN_ID=CAR.ID and TRANSACTION.LAST_UPDATED_DATE=recent_date
   ```

I want to achieve the same result with a single query.
I am not able to come up with anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use can use a scalar subquery

```
select * 
from CAR 
JOIN
(
   select TRAN_ID,LAST_UPDATED_DATE 
   from TRANSACTION 
) t on t.TRAN_ID=CAR.ID and t.LAST_UPDATED_DATE=(select max(last_updated_date)
                               from TRANSACTION 
                               where quality='P' and TYPE='Car')
```

Comment: Thanks @Serg, this query works perfectly. I'm just wondering about the time complexity. could there be any other query that is more efficient.

Comment: Have a look at the execution plan.  It shouldn't be a problem.